# Javascript onclick select sibling that has class

Tags: javascript, onclick, show-hide

I want to show/hide a 2 sibling element `onclick`.

On the page I have multiple `detailLinksItem` which will contain this show/hide function so its necessary to only select the siblings. I need `onclick` to `.style.display = 'block';` for both siblings `.showLess` and `.moreLinksContainer`.

```
            <div class="detailLinksItem">
                <div class="searchIcon"></div>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <div class="detailDate"></div>
                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
                <a href="#" class="showMore" onclick="showStuff(moreLinksContainer); return false;">Show more</a>
                <a href="#" class="showLess" onclick="hideStuff('moreLinksContainer'); return false;" style="display: none;">Show less</a>
                <div class="moreLinksContainer" style="display: none;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Title Goes Here!!</a><div class="moreDetailDate">6 hours</div></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Title Goes Here!!</a><div class="moreDetailDate">1 day</div></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Title Goes Here!!</a><div class="moreDetailDate">3 days</div></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Title Goes Here!!</a><div class="moreDetailDate">1 week</div></li> 
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting a pure JavaScript solution, or are you interested in using tools like jQuery as well if they make it easier?

Comment: I strongly recommend you try jQuery. Is easier than pure JavaScript, and it has been developed to do things like this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showStuff(_container){
       var c = document.getElementsByClassName(_container);
       c[0].style.display = "block";
    }
    function hideStuff(_container){
       var c = document.getElementsByClassName(_container);
       c[0].style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said jQuery is fine:

```
$(function(){
    // When .showMore is clicked
    ​$(".showMore").on("click", function(){
        // Of all the succeeding elements, show those with these classes
        $(this).nextAll(".showLess, .moreLinksContainer").show();    
    });​
    // When .showLess is clicked
    $(".showLess").on("click", function(){
        // Take the next element, and this element, and hide them
        $(this).next().andSelf().hide();    
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EmNsT/
​
With this, you can remove the `onclick` attributes from your links:

```
<a href="#" class="showMore">Show more</a>
<a href="#" class="showLess">Show less</a>
```

Moving your inline-styles out to a stylesheet as well:

```
.showLess,
.moreLinksContainer {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid adding inline event declarations. Ideally, add click events in the document.ready action. Here s a working example for your particular requirement:
http://jsfiddle.net/P8trE/

It also has the required actions for hiding the 'show less' link :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start with jQuery, it will help you to speed up your javascript development. In your case with jQuery u can do :

1. remove your current onclick
2. Include jQUery library into the head
3. $(function() {
   //assign custom events
   $(".showMore").click(function(){
      $(".showMore").hide();//hide show button
      $(".showLess").show();//show hide button
      $(".moreLinksContainer").slideDown(); //open container with effect
   })

   $(".hideStuff").click(function(){
      $(".showLess").hide();//hide hide button
      $(".showMore").show();//show show button
      $(".moreLinksContainer").slideUp(); //hide container
   })
   });

Answer (score 0):

I would add an additional class to the detailLinksItem div using javascript and then use cascading css to show or hide the appropriate child elements.

CSS:

```
.detailLinksItem .showLess, .detailLinksItem .moreLinksContainer {
   display: none;
}
.detailLinksItem.more .showMore {
   display: none;
}
.detailLinksItem.more .showLess, .detailLinksItem.more .moreLinksContainer {
   display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
detailLinksItemElement.className = "detailLinksItem more";
```